# QListView not showing data in model

Tags: c++, qt, qlistview

When I run the program, the list view doesn't show the data in the model I've set up. What am I missing/where am I going wrong?

```
QStandardItemModel mymodel(this);

    QStandardItem *item1 = new QStandardItem("This is item one");
    item1->setData("item", Qt::UserRole + 1);
    mymodel.appendRow(item1);
    QStandardItem *item2 = new QStandardItem("This is item two");
    item2->setData("item", Qt::UserRole + 1);
    mymodel.appendRow(item2);
    QStandardItem *item3 = new QStandardItem("This is item three");
    item3->setData("item", Qt::UserRole + 1);
    mymodel.appendRow(item3);

    ui->listView->setResizeMode(QListView::Adjust);
    ui->listView->setWordWrap(true);
    ui->listView->setVerticalScrollMode(QAbstractItemView::ScrollPerPixel);
    ui->listView->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    ui->listView->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    ui->listView->setModel(&mymodel);
    ui->listView->showNormal();
```

Comment: Probably your `mymodel` object is destroyed when it goes out of scope. Try to allocate it from  the heap.

Comment: Awesome, thanks that fixed it. I'll post the fixed version below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @vahancho - you should allocate from heap. Here's the revised snippet:

```
QStandardItemModel *mymodel = new QStandardItemModel(this);

    QStandardItem *item1 = new QStandardItem("This is item one");
    item1->setData("item", Qt::UserRole + 1);
    mymodel->appendRow(item1);
    QStandardItem *item2 = new QStandardItem("This is item two");
    item2->setData("item", Qt::UserRole + 1);
    mymodel->appendRow(item2);
    QStandardItem *item3 = new QStandardItem("This is item three");
    item3->setData("item", Qt::UserRole + 1);
    mymodel->appendRow(item3);

    ui->listView->setResizeMode(QListView::Adjust);
    ui->listView->setWordWrap(true);
    ui->listView->setVerticalScrollMode(QAbstractItemView::ScrollPerPixel);
    ui->listView->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    ui->listView->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    ui->listView->setModel(mymodel);
    ui->listView->showNormal();
```